# Radio button with input text box

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for radio button with input text box but I couldn't click on the radio button for some reason, how do I fix it?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-13 radio-inline" style="width: 120px;" for="no_mutasi">
    <input type="radio" name="no_mutasi" id="no_mutasi" value="">No Mutasi
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="left: 0px; margin-left: -200px;">
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; left: 0px; margin-left: 200px;">
      <input type="text" size="5" name="no_mutasi" id="no_mutasi" value="" class=" form-control input-block-level" readonly="" />
      <span class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" onclick="myMutasi()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I applied your HTML and can click on the radio button, but could not click focus within the input text field. Unless, the read-only attribute is removed.  Then it is accessible.  Does your question need to be re-framed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue. Please update the snippet I made you with relevant CSS

Answer (score 0):

onclick atribute must be set must be in the input tag not in the span tag

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. It is not clear if OP wants to execute the onclick on click of the radio. It is more likely a CSS issue